# 3 monitors - 2 via external graphics card DVI, and 1 via onboard DVI/VGA port

Tags: display, video, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have been running on two monitors for some time now, but have now acquired a third monitor. Windows detects the third monitor as a generic monitor (as opposed to Samsung xyz ...), but does not seem to output any video display to it.

Currently, my dual monitor setup is running both monitors off the 2 DVI ports of my video card.

My hardware:

**Video card: [XFX AMD Radeon HD 6770 Graphics Card (HD677XZNFC)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C31FJU)**

**Motherboard: [Asus P8Z77­V LK Socket 1155 Intel Z77](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z77V_LK/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use three monitors with [AMD Eyefinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyefinity#Multi-display_technologies) at least one of them has to use the display port (either mini or full). This table is in the wikipedia article for 5800 cards but it applies to the 6770 as well:

[image: table]

If you don't have a monitor with display port as an input you can get an active DisplayPort to DVI-D adapter. I have a 6950 with my main monitor using HDMI one side monitor using DVI-D and the other using this [adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004071ZXA) to DVI. It works very nice the only downside being that occasionally when I wake the computer from sleep the monitor on the adapter doesn't wake up. If I unplug and replug the adapter it works.

To use the onboard controller. Verify that both drivers are installed and up to date and Windows correctly lists the graphics devices in Device Manager. Test using only the onboard controller to ensure that video out is working from there.

Comment: It seems the 6770 only has the normal (full-sized) display port (http://products.xfxforce.com/en-us/Graphics_Cards/AMD_Radeon%E2%84%A2_HD_6770/HD-677X-ZAFV), so I will have to get something like this (http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=692993&csid=_61). Given the price of this cable and another DVI cable, it might just be a better idea to buy another of the exact same card to run in parallel. Is there no way to run 2 displays off the card and one off the onboard output?

Comment: Actually, the link posted isn't even for an active converter, so again, unless I can run off the onboard output for the third monitor, it might just be cheaper to buy another of the exact same card.

Comment: I'm not sure about cheaper $30 vs $100+. DVI cables are cheap <$10 should get you a decent one. WIth two cards you do get crossfire but I still think you need to use displayport to get Eyefinity support (which is really nice to play games with three monitors).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the crash course in [http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/for-consumers/Pages/what-is-eyefinity.aspx](eyefinity). Graphics cards have always been the least important part of my setup, so I'm terribly out of date. Last question - can I have multiple **desktops** with eyefinity, or do the drivers just combine the multiple monitors into one large, pseudo-monitor.

Comment: There are two modes. One where I have three monitors with separate resolutions and an extended Windows desktop. Another called an Eyefinity Display group which creates a single resolution stretched across all the monitors (in my case its 3840x1024).